# Как с использованием CSS изменить выравнивание текста в заголовках таблиц QTableView?

Tags: css, qt

Использую программу от сименса (`WinCC OA`), которая построена на `Qt`. Напрямую, с библиотекой `Qt` в ней работать нельзя, но можно изменять отображение графических объектов, используя `CSS`. Как, используя только `CSS`, определить выравнивание текста в заголовках таблицы `QTableView`.

Пробовал так:

```
 QTableView QHeaderView::section {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

И не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [этой джире](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44870), этот баг еще не закрыт.

Но [есть решение](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) через свойства qt-объектов:

```
QHeaderView { 
    qproperty-defaultAlignment: AlignLeft;
}
```

Comment: Проверил в QSS Редакторе - работает. Но к сожалению, не полностью работает в моей программе. Но видимо, это какие-то баги или особенности программы, которую я использую. Так что можно считать Ваш ответ решением этой проблемы.

Comment: Хорошо, а что за QSS Редактор? Это в Qt Creator'е?

Comment: Это отдельная программа: QSS Editor 0.6.0